# Flutter put an transparent and penetrable screen on top of all other apps and

Tags: flutter, screen, transparent

is there a way in flutter to create an app that simply puts a semi-transparent screen on top of all the other apps etc on the phone? I would like to color the transparent screen and the user should be able to still click on the apps etc. underneath that screen.

I am mostly struggling to find a way to make my screen "penetrable"

Comment: hi! have you found the solution?